# Edit a mySQL record using a PHP form in the simplest manner

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This is the last component in a VERY basic project I've been working on this weekend. I know there are better, more secure ways to do this but I'm limited to the resources available to me. I appreciate you patience with me.

That said - I am trying to write code that allows the user to edit a mySQL record in the table "Employees" under the database "Crosshill". There are 4 fields - "employeeid", "firstname", "lastname", and "department". I found some similar code that did this and I'm trying to modify it to work with my project.

I'm using one page called "revise.php" to do the first step, then an "update.php" page to make the change. The first page is below, and returning a "No entry found" error when it runs. It appears to be connecting fine so I'd assume it's an error in my code modification.

---

revise.php code:

```
  <?php
mysql_connect('####', 'Crosshill', '####') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Crosshill") or die(mysql_error());

$UID = (int)$_GET['employeeid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE employeeid = '$UID'") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $department = $row['department'];

    }
?>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$UID;?>">
First Name: <input type="text" name="ud_firstname" value="<?=$firstname?>"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="ud_lastname" value="<?=$lastname?>"><br>
Department: <input type="text" name="ud_department" value="<?=$department?>"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
<?php

}else{
    echo 'No entry found. <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>';
}
?>
```

---

The second page (update.php) I haven't even gotten to troubleshoot yet, since I'm having this error on the first one. If I can get this first page to work I'll move on to the next one. But here is the code for the "update.php" page in case it's needed. I'll bet it's got errors on it too :)

---

```
<?php
mysql_connect('####, 'Crosshill', '####') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Crosshill") or die(mysql_error());

$ud_ID = (int)$_POST["ID"];

$ud_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ud_firstname"]);
$ud_surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ud_lastname"]);
$ud_FBID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ud_department"]);


$query="UPDATE Employees
            SET firstname = '$ud_firstname', lastname = '$ud_lastname', department = '$ud_department' 
            WHERE ID='$ud_ID'";


mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
    echo "<p>($ud_ID) Record Updated<p>";
}else{
    echo "<p>($ud_ID) Not Updated<p>";
}
?>
```

---

Thanks for being such a supportive community. I know this is very basic stuff for most of you but you have to start somewhere, right?

Comment: Are you passing this `employeeid` GET parameter to `revise.php` and it's correct, existent row id?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. The purpose of this is just to be able to edit records. Am I missing a chunk of code somewhere? There are only 4 fields and 1 table, so I was hoping to figure out how to do this easily. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code shows `revise.php` has to be called with `employeeid` parameter - it then checks if the database has this employee and shows the form filled with his data.

Comment: So should there be a section of code where the user enters that employee ID? If so it was missing from the example on the web.

Comment: In short words: yes. The page should be called something like `revise.php?employeeid=57`

Comment: possible SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a very good start.  Now learn to insert something like:

> **var_dump**($variablename); die;

in your source code in places to debug it a little bit at a time.  For example try inserting:

> var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($query)); die;

to see what mysql is returning.

Also you probably want to move to mysqli (improved) from the older mysql.

Comment: Thank you very much for that help. Every little bit of debugging helps , and I will start looking into using that.

Comment: Also - one of the constraints of this little project is that I don't have access to that "improved" version of the mysql. It's made it a pain from the start, and harder to find good resources since I'm using outdated code. But again - I'm having to work with the tools available

Comment: You're welcome.  You should be able to re-install your local version of php (if you are running localy) and add the mysqli library.  If you are running php on an inaccessible server I would think by now that all servers have this library installed.  Also put this in a php file and run it to see what your capabilities are:  <h4>
    Apache works.<br />
 <?php echo "PHP works.";?><br />

 <?php phpinfo();?><br />
 <?php phpversion();?><br />
</h4>